# Python: Iterating moving Folders

Tags: python, csv, shutil

I have over 52k files of csv files that I need to organize and would like to find an efficient way to do this through python or some other avenue.

Currently I have these folders,

> 2013_Q1
>  2013_Q2
>  2013_Q3
>  2013_Q4
>  2014_Q1 ...

and so on

Within the Quarter folder, i have another folder:

> xxxx20130101_000500_csv
>  xxxx20130101_000500_xml
>   xxxx20130101_001000_csv
>  xxxx20130101_001000_xml

and so on..

within that folder I have the files:

> xxxx20130101_000500_csv.csv
>  xxxx20130101_000500_xml.xml
>   xxxx20130101_001000_csv.csv
>  xxxx20130101_001000_xml.xml

respectively.

I want to go through all the quarter folders and extract only the .csv files from each sub-folder and organize them in a folder by their respective dates.

So within the 2013_Q1 folder, I would like to have

> 20130101
>   20130102...

and so on

And within that 20130101 folder would be

> xxxx20130101_000500_csv.csv
>  xxxx20130101_001000_csv.csv
>   xxxx20130101_001500_csv.csv

Right now I have the python code:

```
import shutil
import os

os.chdir('C:\\...\\Test')

 for f in os.listdir('MovingFolders'):
    folderName = f[-19:-11]

    if not os.path.exists(folderName):
        os.mkdir(folderName)
        shutil.copy(os.path.join('MovingFolders', f), folderName)
    else:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join('MovingFolders', f), folderName)
```

I'm fairly new at python and is still learning, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help if you could provide what errors did you encounter...

Comment: I recommend you look at the python library `glob`. It will let you use a wildcard like `glob.glob("*.csv")` which will return only files with a CSV file extension.

Comment: Where/how did you come up with the `f[-19:-11]`? Seem very path dependent.

Comment: I wanted to auto generate folder name using filename. And that was the string index of the file name i wanted.

Comment: I got this error, PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'MovingFolders\\xxxxxx_20180401_000015_xml'

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.5 and above:

There is a recursive feature in [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) that you could use.
Here's what you do
import glob

loop over glob.glob('root/**/*.csv',recursive = True)